# dynamic loop restTemplate in Spring boot with a list of urls

Tags: spring, spring-boot, multithreading, parallel-processing, resttemplate

I have a List of URLs...
The size of the list changes every time.
Now I need below code convert to dynamic... I want to use dynamic loop and set `CountDownLatch`  as dynamic to make sure all the urls have the answer, if that's possible.

```
public class ApiCallerService {
    
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
    public ApiCallerService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public Map<String, String> callApis() throws InterruptedException {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        String response1 = "";
        String response2 = "";
        String response3 = "";

        String url1 = "http://....";
        String url2 = "http://....";
        String url3 = "http://....";

        new Thread(() -> {
            response1 = restTemplate.getForObject(url1, String.class);
            latch.countDown();
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            response2 = restTemplate.getForObject(url2, String.class);
            latch.countDown();
        }).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            response3 = restTemplate.getForObject(url3, String.class);
            latch.countDown();
        }).start();

        latch.await();

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(url1, response1);
        map.put(url2, response2);
        map.put(url3, response3);

        return map;
    }

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Java Streams for dynamic processing like below

```
    String[] urls = {"http://....", "http://....", "http://...."};
    int noOfThreads = 3; //This can be urls.length also
    ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(noOfThreads);
    Map<String, String> map = forkJoinPool.submit(() -> Arrays.stream(urls).parallel().map(url -> {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        return Pair.of(url, response);
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getFirst, Pair::getSecond))).get();
    forkJoinPool.shutdown();
```

Comment: Also, list of urls can be dynamically configured using the '@ConfigurationProperties' as mentioned by @Pawan Kumar

Comment: I don't see the added benefit of the newly created forkjoinpool, as the `parallel` won't use it, it will still use the default forkjoinpool. So this could be simplified even more.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why **parallel** wont use the newly create **ForkJoinPool**?

Comment: My bad, apparently it does work like this. I was under the impression that `parallel` always uses `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` regardless of what you did, so you would need to reconfigure the common one. There is some very confusing material out there. However I see no need to specify your own pool here and just calling `parallel` would suffice.

Comment: Yes, we can use commonPool also but no. of threads will depend on the system configuration as it uses **no. of cores - 1** threads. And I think as per the problem, he wants to use new threads for each task.

Comment: You shouldn't really be creating threads, as those will linger around (even after the shutdown of the pool) and eventually take up memory. As Threads are bound to CPU cores, they are quite hard to GC in the end.

Comment: Correctly said, I also do prefer the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` mostly but it's purely depends on different scenarios. Whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Spring Boot utilize the Spring Task abstraction to submit jobs async and get the results. Spring Boot by default creates a `TaskExecutor` (configurable through `spring.task` namespace) which you can use for this.

```java
public class ApiCallerService {
    
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    public ApiCallerService(RestTemplate restTemplate, AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    public Map<String, String> callApis() throws InterruptedException {
       
       List<String> urls = ... // List of urls;
       List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList();
       for (String url : urls) {
         futures.add(taskExecutor.submitCompletable(() -> getResult(url))
       }
       return futures.stream()
                .map( (cf) -> get(cf))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Result::url, Result::response);
                
    }

    private Result get(CompletableFuture<Result> cf) {
      try {
        return cf.get();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
      }
    }

    private String getResult(String url) {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        return new Result(url, response);
    }
}

public record Result(String url, String response) {}
```

Another option is to use `WebClient` which is reactive (and thus async) by default and allows to collect the results as well.

```java
public class ApiCallerService {
    
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public ApiCallerService(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public Map<String, String> callApis() throws InterruptedException {
       
       List<String> urls = ... // List of urls;
       return Flux.fromIterable(urls)
                .flatMap( this::getResult)
                .collectMap(Result::url, Result::response)
                .block();                
    }

    private Mono<Result> getResult(String url) {
        Mono<String> response = webClient.get().uri(url)
                                         .retrieve()
                                         .bodyToMono(String.class);
        return response.map( (res) -> new Result(url, res));
    }
}

public record Result(String url, String response) {}
```

Either way don't create your own `Thread` instances, use a pool as if you keep creating threads eventually you will run out of resources.